# Combine multiple operations in Python

Tags: python, list

```
the_line = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

b = list(range(12))
b.sort(reverse=True)

c = [i * b[i] for i in the_line]
d = sum(c)/78
```

Is there a way to combine these operations to an one-liner?

Comment: Is `the_line` always sequential numbers like that, or could it be any 12 numbers?

Comment: @Barmar ```the_line```is from ```something[-12]``` to ```something[-1]```

Comment: I have to ask: *why* do you feel the need to combine all this into, a single line? From [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *"Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex."*

Comment: @SiHa Because it saves me 20 lines of other code. The data in ```the_list``` is dynamic and with that one_liner I safe tons of "copy and paste'.

Comment: That's what functions are for, surely? And I don't understand how the list being dynamic has any bearing, other than that you would need to get the length of the list rather than using hard-coded values.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = sum(i * (11 - i) for i in the_line) / 78
```

If `the_line` can be something else:

```
d = sum(j * (11 - i) for i, j in enumerate(the_line)) / 78
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = sum([i * v for i,v in enumerate(sorted(list(range(12)), reverse=True))])/78
```

Comment: I just wanted to give all the options so as OP can use accordingly

Comment: It should be `range(11, -1, -1)`, no need to call bunch of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Also it's possible to do using `map()`:

```
sum(map(lambda x: x[1] * (11 - x[0]), enumerate(the_line))) / 78
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = sum(x * y for x, y in zip(the_line, range(11, -1, -1))) / 78
```